# Bootstrap modal hide not working with jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a modal dialog made with bootstrap, like this:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myid">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
       Loading...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I make a javascript function like this:

```
$(document)
            .ajaxStart(function () {
                $('#myid').modal('show');
            })
            .ajaxStop(function () {
                $('#myid').modal('hide');
            });
```

But when I call some ajax function the modal appears but no hide. I put console.log in both functions (ajaxStart and ajaxStop) and it was called. when I replace ajaxStop as below, everything works, but not appears right.

```
$(document)
                .ajaxStart(function () {
                    $('#myid').modal('show');
                })
                .ajaxStop(function () {
                    $('#myid').hide();
                    $('.fade').hide();
                });
```

The main problema is when I call another modal within ajax, then I click in link, loading ajax appears, request is send to server, response returns, modal with data from request appears, but loading modal not hide.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

You have to set a timeout.
That works for me:

```
setTimeout(function () { $("#myid").modal("hide"); }, 500);
```

Comment: This might not work when the server takes more time to response than 500 ms.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try binding to the ajax events like this:

```
$("#myid").bind({
   ajaxStart: function() { $(this).show(); },
   ajaxStop: function() { $(this).hide(); }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `$('#myid').hide();` in ajaxStop, use `$('#myid').modal('hide');`

Answer (score 0):

Hide processing does not occur, probably because the closing is done without performing the modal opening operation. This worked for me;

```
setTimeout(() => {$('#ModalExpeditionSeal').modal('hide')}, 350)
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use as the following:

$("#myid").modal().hide()